# File Upload in the KendoGrid on click of Custom button

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to upload the files on Custom button click  and whatever filename i get must be mentioned in the First column of the grid and in the Second one i can put the description for that file and in the third provision for deleting it.How this is possible?
My Code goes as follows:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Invoice.Models.ViewModels.Setup.FilesViewModel>()
    .Name("FileGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {

        columns.Bound(p => p.FileName).Title("File Name").Width(100).ClientTemplate("#= AccountTransactionItemHead#" + "<input type='hidden' class='AccountTransactionItemHead'  value='#=AccountTransactionItemHead#' />");
        columns.Bound(p => p.Description).Title("Description").Width(140).ClientTemplate("#= AccountTransactionItemDescription#" + "<input type='hidden' class='AccountTransactionItemDescription'  value='#=AccountTransactionItemDescription#' />");

        columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Width(110);
    })
    .ToolBar(toolbar =>
    {
        toolbar.Template(@<text>
@(Html.Kendo().Upload()
            .Name("files")
)      </text>);
    })
            .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .Batch(true)
                .ServerOperation(false)
                .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
                .Model(model =>
                {
                    model.Id(p => p.FileID);
                })

            .Read("Editing_Read", "Grid")
            .Destroy("Editing_Destroy", "Grid")
        )
)
```

[image]

Comment: after  you upload thye file  you need to refresh the grid

Comment: yes but how to get the file name in the first column on upload from the button which wud be in the toolbar of the grid

Comment: when you uplad the file you shod get that data

Comment: let me share the Image what Exactly i want..

Comment: now u get to know what Exactly i want..

Comment: you want to add delete button to the grid and delete that file

Comment: yes On Select File Button which is a Custom button in the toolbar of the kendoGrid the Files must be uploaded and the name of the file must be shown in the First column and in the second cloumn i must be able to insert the Description Manually and in the last column i must be able to delete the file and so on for rest of the rows as well